# Iterate over QTableWidget cells in constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, qt-designer, qtablewidget

I would like to set a subclass of QTableWidget read-only from its constructor but I cannot find a way to put the flag on all the items, and the code shown does not work since the columnCount and rowCount are called in the constructor, and therefore returning 0.

```
for (int i=0;i<this->columnCount();i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<this->rowCount();j++) {
        this->item(i,j)->setFlags(Qt::ItemFlag::NoItemFlags);
    }
}
```

Since the headers were initialized through Qt Designer with the double click form, I do not have a way to know the column/row count from code (except by hard coding it, but I would like to avoid that), and I could not find any method to apply the flags to all items.

I also have seen a few [workarounds working on the modification event itself to prevent data modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001144/disable-user-to-click-over-qtablewidget), but I would also prefer avoiding that.

Is there a way to set those flags correctly or do I have to get rid of the Qt Designer part to add all the header initialization in the constructor?

Comment: Does your table have fixed number of rows and columns?

Comment: Yes, once initialized, the size will not be changing at all

Comment: Can't you change item flags in Qt Designer as well then?

Comment: The only place I found to do so in the Designer is to click each cell in the editing form and set it as read only, I guess that a workaround I wanted to avoid would still be better than doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your QTableView is being populated in auto-generated `setupUi()` (first widget is created, then items are added), you could add a method like `setReadOnly(bool)` to your subclass (which I suppose the widget in Designer is promoted to) and call it explicitly after `setupUi()`. Will even be more flexible since then you'd be able to use this subclass with non-read-only tables as well.

Comment: Works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Hey This solves your problem...

```
for (int i=0;i< ui->tableWidget->rowCount();i++) {
        for (int j=0;j< ui->tableWidget->columnCount();j++) {
            QTableWidgetItem *item =  ui->tableWidget->item(i,j);
            item->setFlags(Qt::NoItemFlags);
        }
    }
```

Just try this, you can easily figure out the issue with your code...
rowCount() and coloumnCount() api should be aligned properly and its item() API , not itemAT().. Please Check.